# cannot use &ingredients (type *[]foo.bar) as type []*foo.bar in assignment

Tags: go, variable-assignment

I use GoLang v1.5.1 and I get this weird error or I missed something.

in a package called model I have defined the following:

```
type SearchResultRow struct {
    ID          int               `json:"id"`
    Name        string            `json:"name"`
    Type        string            `json:"type"`
    Notes       *string           `json:"notes"`
    AddedBy     *string           `json:"added_by"`
    Source      *string           `json:"source"`
    Ratings     *int              `json:"ratings"`
    IVer        *int              `json:"i_ver"`
    Ingredients []*IngredientType `json:"ingredients"`
    Accessories []*AccessoryType  `json:"accessories"`
}

type AccessoryType struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    IVer *int   `json:"i_ver"`
}

type IngredientType struct {
    Name   string  `json:"name"`
    Flavor *string `json:"flavor"`
    ItID   *int    `json:"it_id"`
    IID    *int    `json:"i_id"`
    IVer   *int    `json:"i_ver"`
}
```

and in my main code I have

```
    var currentFinalRow model.SearchResultRow
    var ingredients []model.IngredientType
    ...
    err = json.Unmarshal(row.Ingredients, &ingredients)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    currentFinalRow.Ingredients = &ingredients
```

and I get the error: `cannot use &ingredients (type *[]model.IngredientType) as type []*model.IngredientType in assignment`

did I miss something? isn't it the same type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is a pointer to a slice, and one is a slice of pointers.

To fix things, change `var ingredients []model.IngredientType` to `var ingredients []*model.IngredientType` so it matches the type of your struct field. And then change the assignment to `currentFinalRow.Ingredients = ingredients` without the "address-of" operator.

A (shorter) alternative would be `err = json.Unmarshal(row.Ingredients, &currentFinalRow.Ingredients)` so that the json unmarshalling works directly on your struct field.